# AppShell- Failed to Navigate Back, Ambiguous routes matched for.... but i've only registered routes once

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, app-shell

I am building an Xamarin Forms app for iOS and Android.
I registered my routes in AppShell.xaml.cs globally like this:

```
**-AppShell.xaml.cs-**
Routes.Add(nameof(HousingFolderPage), typeof(HousingFolderPage));
Routes.Add(nameof(HousingFolderDetailsPage), typeof(HousingFolderDetailsPage));
```

In my tabbar I have a tab "MoreServicePage" which shows a list of items. So far so good.

```
**-MoreServicePage.cs-**
private async void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"HousingFolderPage");
}
```

Now when HousingFolderPage is showing, I have no problem navigating back from here. HousingFolderPage also shows another list, but when I push to next page, I'm not able to come back.

```
**-HousingFolderPage.xaml.cs-**
private async void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("HousingFolderDetailsPage");
}
```

Error message:

> [0:] Shell: Failed to Navigate Back: System.ArgumentException: Ambiguous routes matched for: //D_FAULT_TabBar2/IMPL_MoreServicePage/MoreServicePage/HousingFolderPage matches found: //D_FAULT_TabBar2/IMPL_MoreServicePage/MoreServicePage/HousingFolderPage,//D_FAULT_TabBar2/IMPL_MoreServicePage/MoreServicePage/HousingFolderPage
> Parameter name: uri

I have only registered the routs in AppShell programmaticly (AppShell.xaml.cs) and no other places not even in the AppShell.xaml.

*PS. this seems to happen everywhere where I navigate 2 pages deep, while 1 page deep works without a problem*

I have created a simple Xamarin Forms Application to reproduce this issue. As you will see, you are able to navigate back from page 2, but not from page 3 to page 4 nor from page 4 to page 3.

[Download test repo](https://github.com/nabilakhlaque/Xamarin-forms-navigation-issue)

Comment: How do you navigate back?

Comment: None of the ways work. Same error which ever way I choose. I have tried:
"Navigation back button" and "Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an similar issue abaout [GotoAsync build in back button does not go back to previous page, when working with 3 or more pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67653489/gotoasync-build-in-back-button-does-not-go-back-to-previous-page-when-working-w).

And the cause for this problem is you register the first page both in the xaml and the AppShell.cs.

I have tested the repo sample you posted on the github. When I deleted the `Route="Page1"` in the `<ShellContent Route="Page1" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}" />`. The navigation worked well.

So you can check the if there is any page you register route both in the AppShell.xams and AppShell.xaml.cs or not.