# Shell navigate to same page from more other pages

Tags: shell, navigation, maui

In my .net maui app I have a help page, called "AboutHelp", that I want to navigate to from more other pages. How do I do that ? My problem is that the Back arrow button doesn't work when I navigate to the AboutHelp page from other than the Main page, "MainPage".

If I navigate to a page I called "ControlPanel" with the command

```
[RelayCommand]
public async Task ControlsButton_Clicked()
{
    var prams = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {
            "BtnSaveAllRawTxtAsIsEnbled"
            ,
            BtnSaveAllRawTxtAsIsEnbled
        },
        {
            "ButtonSaveAllTextAsIsEnabled"
            ,
            ButtonSaveAllTextAsIsEnabled
        },
        {
            "ButtonClearIsEnabled"
            ,
            ButtonClearIsEnabled
        },
        {
            "ButtonIDoIsEnabled"
            ,
            ButtonIDoIsEnabled
        },
        {
            "FormulaHolderIsEnabled"
            ,
            FormulaHolderIsEnabled
        }
    };

    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync
        (
            nameof(ControlPanel)
            , true
            , prams
        );
}
```

and then from there navigate to the AboutHelp page with the command

```
[RelayCommand]
public void HelpClicked()
{
    _ = Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(ControlPanel)}/{nameof(AboutHelp)}", true);
}
```

hen the Back arrow button works from the AboutHelp page back to the ControlPanel page but then there is no Back arrow button above the ControlPanel page.

My AppShell.xaml.cs looks like this:

```
namespace PdfCalculator;

public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainPage), typeof(MainPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ControlPanel), typeof(ControlPanel));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(AboutHelp), typeof(AboutHelp));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(LineChartView), typeof(LineChartView));
    }
}
```

Navigate from MainPage to ControlPanel to AboutHelp

Would expect Back arrow button (that worked) on all pages.

Comment: When you start with `//`, you are telling Shell to clear nav stack, then push that path. Thus the back behavior you saw. Did you try `..GoToAsync($"{nameof(AboutHelp)}")`?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve he wants to go to ControlPanel/AboutHelp, not just AboutHelp.

Comment: But he's going there while on ControlPanel, and has a route "AboutHelp"; doesn't the simple form of GoToAsync simply push it onto the current nav stack? Thus first back would go to ControlPanel, second to what was before ControlPanel on stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have create a new project to test the `Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(ControlPanel)}/{nameof(AboutHelp)}", true);` in the **ControlPanel Page**, but there was nothing heppened. It will not navigate from the **ControlPanel Page** to **AboutHelp Page**.

According to the [official document about the Absolute routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0#absolute-routes):

> the code such as `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//animals/monkeys");` is used for navigates to the page for the monkeys route, with the route being defined on a ShellContent object. The ShellContent object that represents the monkeys route is a child of a FlyoutItem object, whose route is animals

But in your code about registering the route, the **AboutHelp Page** is not a child of the **ControlPanel Page**. So you can try to use `Shell.Current.GoToAsync({nameof(AboutHelp), true)` directly.

In addition, there is a bug about the navigation back button. When you register the route both in the AppShell.xaml and the AppShell.xaml.cs. Such as used both `<ShellContent Route="MainPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />` and  `Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainPage), typeof(MainPage));`. The back button will not work since the third page in the navigation stack. You need to delete the `Route="MainPage"` in the `<ShellContent>`.

For more information, you can refer to this case about [AppShell- Failed to Navigate Back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75848109/appshell-failed-to-navigate-back-ambiguous-routes-matched-for-but-ive-onl/75851541#75851541).

Comment: It solved my problem In my case I must have 1) the route to MainPage in AppShell.xaml, 2) all other routes must be in AppShell.xaml.cs